# How to get rpart to work on relatively large number rows (~100k)?

Tags: r, bigdata, rpart

I have a clustering need for my simple but a bit large data set. It has 3 columns and about 120k rows, plus all the data is numeric. I tried to use rpart but got this lovely error.

```
Error in rep(1, numclass^2) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(rep(1, numclass^2) - diag(numclass), numclass) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

The function has no kinky stuff either.

```
fit<-rpart(respVar ~ Var1 + Var2, data=varData, method="class")
```

I have no problem with 1k rows. It is somewhat slow in 10k rows, but still works. No NA values in the dataset. Currently trying that on a Macbook Air, but will try it on a Mac Mini also.

I suspect it is a memory issue, but the warning message concerns me. Is there some workaround to get the clustering work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think so,

It's same error when we tried to use rep function with huge number like :

```
> x <- rep(0,120000*12000000)
Error in rep(0, 120000 * 1.2e+07) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

But i just guess, i don't know exactly

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Now I need something similar to avoid such lovely memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but after searching around, I haven't found any solutions.

One way i worked around it is by changing the method="class" to method="anova" (changing from a classification to a regression), and it worked for me.

How many levels are there in your response variable? I think if you have quite a lot of levels for your data set, maybe you could try method="anova"